# Can I pass command-line arguments to Abaqus python?

Tags: python

I have an abaqus python script I've been using for a parametric study. It is exhausting to go into the code and edit it every time I want to run different options. I'd like to be able to pass the script arguments so that I can run different options without needing to change the code.

I'd like to do something like this...

```
abaqus cae script='Script.py --verbose --data=someData.dat'
```

I've tried the above and I've also tried

```
abaqus python Script.py --verbose --data=someData.dat
```

With no success. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Could you clarify something please? Are you wondering how to access command line arguments within a python script, or the syntax for adding command line arguments to abaqus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Abaqus Scripting User's Manual:

Arguments can be passed into the script by entering -- on the command line, followed by the arguments separated by one or more spaces. These arguments will be ignored by the Abaqus/CAE execution procedure, but they will be accessible within the script. For more information, see “Abaqus/CAE execution,” Section 3.2.5 of the Abaqus Analysis User’s Manual, and “Abaqus/Viewer execution,” Section 3.2.6 of the Abaqus Analysis User’s Manual.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Now that you mention it I remember reading that, but when I read through the documentation again I couldn't find it for the life of me.

Answer (score 9):

Good find Schickmeister. It was not clear to me how to implement, so here is an example

launch abaqus python in cmd.exe

```
abaqus cae noGUI
```

enter some python code

```
>>>import sys
>>>print sys.argv
['C:\\ABAQUS\\6.13-2SE\\code\\bin\\ABQcaeK.exe', '-cae', '-noGUI', '-lmlog',     'ON', '-tmpdir', 'C:\\Windows\\TEMP']
>>>quit()
```

See how many arguments show up? That's why we need to grab the last one
now launch your python script with argument "test.odb"

```
abaqus cae noGUI=odb_to_video.py -- test.odb
```

and retrieve the last argument in your script with

```
odbname = sys.argv[-1]
myOdb = visualization.openOdb(path=odbname)
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible. Let's see an example if you try to run a command like this:

```
abaqus python script.py 30 40
```

30 and 40 are the arguments that the distance.py script will take. Inside the script in python, you should take the first argument as:

```
import sys


def someFunction(x,y):

    #some code

    return someThing


if __name__ == "__main__":

   x = sys.argv[1]
   y = sys.argv[2]

   returnedVal = someFunction(x,y)

   print (returnedVal)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Shickmeister 's answer was exactly what I was looking for, but just to be clear with everything relevant to the question, the latest version of abaqus is far behind the latest version of python. Abaqus currently uses python 2.6, which means [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html) is not available. I had to switch to using the deprecated [optparse](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/optparse.html) library. Luckily the difference between the two was minor.